# DateTime Format Issue in C#

Tags: c#

DateTime is `2022-02-03T22:12:30.05Z`

I have the DateTime format as `DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")`

It is getting displayed as `2022-02-03T22:12:30.050Z`

With that format, `0.05Z` is getting displayed as `0.050Z`

If in some cases, I have 3 digits before Z, it is displaying right. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `fff` part of the format has 3 `f`s, which means show 3 digits for that position, and therefore `0.050Z` is expected. You could hide this by only using 2 `f`s (`...mm:ss.ffZ`), but then the "in some cases I have three digits" results would be wrong. So I need to ask: how is the trailing `0` breaking things for you? It's the _**same instant**_ either way, no?

Comment: It sounds like you might need `F` instead of `f`. Capital `F` doesn't show trailing `0`.  So it would end in `.FFFZ`.  [Read the documentation, always a good place to start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: This worked. Thanks